# CMD/BATCH: Search computer C Drive for a Folder Name and make the address the working location

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript, cmd

I basically have over 5 computers(running windows xp,vista,7,8,10, most run win10) i run at home, most but not all computers have different main drive letters(C: or E: or F: etc), and I currently access a folder on these machines manually and I would like to make it more automatic.

I wanted to make a simple batch script that scans the computer(s) for a folder called "Visuals2579211"(this folder name doesn't change on any of my systems, inside this folder is a few cache/txt/tmp files and a program(exe) I made for myself.

So is it possible to search each computer for the folder name:"Visuals2579211" using batch and then make this folders location become the current working directory for further manipulation?

I tried a few scripts and snips of code i found on google and searched around here on stackoverflow as well of coarse, but none of the results are quite what i am after.

I don't mind if the batch script has to create a VBS script or txt file(s) and run them and delete them after with the batch if necessary but I really would like to access my applications folder with a batch file as it would save me a hell of a lot of time. I also plan to have this batch file placed on the Desktop of each machine, So I am searching from the desktop for the Visuals folder.

I know i can make a batch to change CD etc for each machine and specify the current path of each machine but i want the batch to be universal and work on all machines instead of making a batch for each one as these machines drive letters may change over time and i often create and rebuild new machines etc. Any ideas out there?

Comment: You need to start yourself and then ask questions when you get in trouble.  SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: @TobyAllen, I have read through the BATCH and MS-DOS commands on the net and searched google and stackoverflow before asking, i honestly cannot find what i am looking for, i have tried many of the results that came up, when i cant find an answer to my issues myself i ask for help. Stackoverflow is about helping people. I have no idea what code i started with would even be the best way to START this otherwise i would of posted over 50 of the trials that failed. Posting unfinished scripts that are faulty, wrong and possibly insecure are not very handy for anyone and they shouldnt be posted.

Comment: The purpose of Stack Overflow is to help you finish your script that isn't working, and nothing more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test this:

It checks each drive in order and stops at the first drive with the folder.

The ? is to give a wildcard for the `for /d /r` search command and it can be supplied in different ways.

```
@echo off
set "folder="
for %%a in (c e f) do if not defined folder (
   pushd "%%a:\"
      for /d /r %%b in (Visua?s2579211) do set "folder=%%b"
   popd
)
if defined folder %comspec% /k pushd "%folder%"
```

Comment: thank you for your response, i have tried the above,when i run this is there a way to check if it worked or failed? Is the wildcard correct or should it be Visuals?2579211 or Visuals2579211?

Comment: What happened when you ran it?  A cmd prompt should open in the right folder.  The wildcard is fine as it is.

Comment: Thanks, i didnt realise it takes a while to load. Is there a way i can alter this so instead of making the batch push this as the address, instead can i store it as a path to use to delete files?

Comment: It's searching one or more complete drives - and the type of drive and size and number of folders/files all affects it too.  I don't follow your other point.  You might like to try www.dostips.com or computerhelp forum rather than stackoverflow for these kinds of questions.  People will vote to close them here as this is not the primary purpose of SO.